# Tried the standard fixes - still getting FATAL: Module i2c-bcm2708 not found

Tags: i2c

I've removed the offending lines in (namely all lines)-

```
/etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf
```

I've adjusted `/etc/modules` to read:

```
snd-bcm2835
i2c-dev
i2c-bcm2708
```

When I try: `modprobe i2c-dev`
I receive no errors.

However, when I reboot I or try `modprobe i2c-bcm2708`
I see:

```
FATAL: Module i2c-bcm2708 not found.
```

Similarly, with aptitude install i2c-tools I see the message:

```
/run/udev or .udevdb or .udev presence implies active udev.  Aborting MAKEDEV invocation.
```

Both

```
i2cdetect -y 0
i2cdetect -y 1
```

throw back errors.

As far as Raspberry Pi Model, `cat /proc/cpuinfo` tells me:

```
processor       : 0
model name      : ARMv6-compatible processor rev 7 (v6l)
BogoMIPS        : 2.00
Features        : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp java tls 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xb76
CPU revision    : 7

Hardware        : BCM2708
Revision        : 000f
Serial          : 00000000bf083f1f
```

Answer (score 1):

Use i2c_dev and i2c_bcm2708.

edited to add:

I assumed i2c-dev and i2c-bcm2708 were different symbols to i2c_dev and i2c_bcm2708.  In the context of modprobe they appear to be synonyms (- and _ are interchangeable) so my assumption was wrong.

Comment: Not sure if this works. I did an aptitude dist-upgrade and the problem went away... Thank you though.

Comment: You are right.  - and _ seem to be synonyms in module names.  Both seem to work on my Pi.  I didn't know that.